# Find CDF of $Z:=\min\{X,Y\}$

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Let be $X,Y$ independent random variables with $X\sim\mathcal{U}(\{0,1\})$ and $Y\sim\mathcal{U}(\{0,1,2\})$. Compute the CDF of $Z:=\min\{X,Y\}$.

**My idea:**

$$
\begin{align*}
P(\min\{X,Y\}\leq x) &= 1-P(\min\{X,Y\}>x)\\
&= 1-P(\{X>x\}\cap\{Y>x\})\\
&=1-P(X>x)\cdot P(Y>x)\\
&= 1-(1-P(X\leq x))(1-P(Y\leq x))\\
&=1-(1-F_X(x))(1-F_Y(x)),
\end{align*}
$$
while

$$F_X(x)=\begin{cases} 0 &,x<a\\ \frac{x-a}{b-a} &, x\in[a,b]\\ 1&, x>b \end{cases}.$$

What sould I do next?

Comment: You are almost there. However, if the definition of $X$ you gave is exact (i.e., uniform on $\{0,1\}$), then the cdf of $X$ is not what you gave (first, there is no $a,b$ in the problem; second, it must be a piecewise-constant function with two jumps.) Then, do a distinction of cases in the expression you get for the cdf of $\min(X,Y)$: $x < 0$, $x\in[0,1)$, $x\in[1,2)$, and $x\geq 2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gave a generic definition of the CDF of uniform *continuous* distributions.

You have two specific uniform *discrete* distributions.   These will have step functions.

The CDF of the minimum of those RV will also be a step function, although the steps will not be *uniform* .   We also know the support of $Z$ since: $\min\{X, Y\}\in \{0,1,2\}$

$$\begin{align}F_X (x) & = \begin{cases} 0 & x < 0 \\ \tfrac 12 & : 0\leq x < 1 \\ 1 & : 1\leq x\end{cases} \\[2ex] F_Y (y) & = \begin{cases} 0 & y < 0 \\ \tfrac 13 & : 0\leq y < 1 \\ \tfrac 2 3 & : 1\leq y < 2 \\ 1 & : 2\leq y\end{cases} \\[3ex] F_Z(z) & = 1-(1-F_X(z))(1-F_Y(z)) \\[1ex] & = \begin{cases} 0 & z < 0 \\ ? & : 0\leq z < 1 \\ ? & : 1\leq z < 2 \\ 1 & : 2\leq z\end{cases} \end{align}$$

Can you complete?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $X$ takes on two possible values and $Y$ takes on three possible values, then the pair $(X,Y)$ has six possible values, each one equally likely (since $X$ and $Y$ are independent and each one has uniform distribution). This means you can enumerate the possible values for $Z:=\min(X,Y)$ and determine their probabilities (construct a table!). You'll find that $Z$ takes value $0$ with probability $2/3$ and value $1$ with probability $1/3$, which is enough information to determine the CDF.